# How to add item in DataGrid (smart way)

Tags: c#, wpf

Actually I read a lot of solution but are too long.
There is no way for make something like this:

```
DataGrid.Items.Add("element");
```

?

Comment: Yeah, rows... I already have a DataGrid structure, now I want populate them through the code.

Comment: If you use MVVM, (Bind the DataGrid with your ViewModel containing the ItemsSource), you just need to do ItemsSource.Add('element'). That is the most accepted/recommended way to work in WPF.

Comment: Can you show me a bit example, please?

Comment: Haven't gone through it all, but this seems to be a very good full example of how to use MVVM with Datagrid, if you don't have experience with MVVM I advise you to go over it all, will be very enlightening and also will set you off in a good Path for working with WPF in general: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/42548/MVVM-and-the-WPF-DataGrid (MVVM is the smart way to work with WPF :) )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're using WPF, you'll want to create a List then use `dataGrid.ItemsSource = yourClassToShowList;`. This will auto populate columns and row items for you. Upon the event `SelectedItemChanged` you can grab the single (or multiple) selected `YouClassToShow`'s. WPF make it really simple to bind data to UI controls.

Here are some examples:

XAML

```
<DataGrid x:Name="dg" Margin="10,32,10,111" AlternatingRowBackground="White" SelectionChanged="dgDailyMediaReport_SelectionChanged" IsReadOnly="True" AutoGenerateColumns="False" SelectionMode="Single" >
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="{Binding Status}" Width="75">
            <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Grid>
                        <ProgressBar  Height="20"  Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Minimum="0" Maximum="500" Value="{Binding TotalProgress, Mode=OneWay}"></ProgressBar>
                        <Label HorizontalAlignment="Center" Content="{Binding TotalPercent,Mode=OneWay}"></Label>
                    </Grid>
                </DataTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        </DataGridTemplateColumn>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="NAME" Binding="{Binding Name}" Foreground="DarkRed" />
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="AGE" Binding="{Binding Age}" />

    </DataGrid.Columns>

    <DataGrid.ContextMenu>
        <ContextMenu>
            <MenuItem x:Name="menuShowInFolder" Header="Show In Folder" Click="menuShowInFolder_Click"/>
        </ContextMenu>
    </DataGrid.ContextMenu>
</DataGrid>
```

C#

Window_Loaded event:

```
List<YourClass> yourClassList = yourClassListRepo.GetYourClasses();
dg.ItemsSource = yourClassList;
```

dg_SelectionChanged event:

```
if(dg.SelectedItems.Count > 0){
    foreach(YourClass yourClass in (List<YourClass> dg.SelectedItems)){
        MessageBox.Show(yourClass.Name);
    }
}
```

`Binding="{Binding Name}"` "Name" in this context is your objects public property.

So you'll need a public access method like `public String Name {get;set}`

Side note: To change an object's property value and have it auto show, you'll need `INotifyPropertyChanged` on the Object itself:

Person class:

```
public class Person: INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    #region PROPERTY_CHANGED_EVENTS
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;
        if (handler != null) handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
    protected bool SetField<T>(ref T field, T value, string propertyName)
    {
        if (EqualityComparer<T>.Default.Equals(field, value)) return false;
        field = value;
        OnPropertyChanged(propertyName);
        return true;
    }
    #endregion

    private String _name;
    public String Name { get { return _name; } set { SetField(ref _name, value, "Name"); } }
}
```

Comment: where are the method getyourclasses()? because when I add the code in the window load is underlined in red.

Comment: @HaroldFinch, `GetYourClasses()` is a generic name for a method that returns a List<YourClass> that has been populated from a data source.

Answer (score 1):

You should be trying to solve this by using MVVM principles. In other words, databind the datagrid to a collection in a viewmodel, and add your item to the *collection*.